# How to start separate process in Ant Task

Tags: ant

I want to define target in Ant build file
Something like this

```
<target name="startEclipse" >
      <exec executable="D:\Installable\eclipse\eclipse neon\eclipse.exe">
      </exec>
</target>
```

But problem is command "ant startEclipse" is not finished as long as eclipse is running.
If I ctrl+z on Ant command, it stops eclipse too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, we have to add attribute spawn="true"
In exec tag. If we don't provide default value is false. With true it will fork out another process for exec command.